# What is the most efficient way to do the String comparison?

Tags: c#

Both do the same thing. What is the most efficient way to compare two strings?
Equals() or Compare()? Are there any differences?

```
        if (String.Equals(StringA, StringB, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Your code goes here
        }

        if (String.Compare(StringA, StringB, true) == 0)
        {
            // Your code goes here
        }
```

Comment: Are you talking about speed? Because if you are, a simple loop and Stopwatch will answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just try it out with a microbenchmark and find out?
Let each statement run atleast 100000 times.

Answer (score 3):

Equals() will tell you whether they are equal or not. Compare() will tell you *how* equal they are. It "returns an integer that indicates their relative position in the sort order". As for performance, basically the same for almost all purposes.